# Perl: How to match same word in each line until different word in a new line

Tags: perl

I'm trying to print same type data with different values in each line. After that combine each type value with corresponding name(MMaaa/gg/dd).
The data example is shown as below. Take group 1 as an example, name is in format of MMxxxx/xxx/xxxx (MMaaa/gg/dd) and type value is ID03. A group is consist of fruit(e.g:apple), fruit name(e.g:MMbb/gggg/iii) and type values(e.g:ID02,ID04,ID05) or two type fruits and names (e.g:apple and orange).

A only combination of apple name and its type values is what I want. 
I tried to print the combination to get expected result but fail. So far I have tried this:

```
while (@array = <FILE>) {
    foreach $line (@array) {
        if($line =~ m/apple\s{1}MM/) {
            $a = $line;
            if($line =~ m/(type)/) {
                $b = $line;
            }
        }
        print "\n$a/$b\n";
    }
}
```

---

DATA:

```
apple                    
apple MMaaa/gg/dd        
type  ID03_________________group 1               
apple                   
apple MMsss/ff/dd        
orange MMmm/ss             
orange MMll/fff______________group 2             
apple                    
apple MMbb/gggg/iii      
type  ID02             
type  ID04             
type  ID05_________________group 3               
apple                 
apple MMhh/jj/lll       
orange MMff/gg_______________group 4           
apple                 
apple MMll/pp/ooo       
type  ID09             
type  ID03_________________group 5  
..  
..  
.  
.
```

expected result:

```
aaa/gg/dd/ID03  
bb/gggg/iii/ID02  
bb/gggg/iii/ID04  
bb/gggg/iii/ID05  
ll/pp/ooo/ID09  
ll/pp/ooo/ID03
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $first;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    $first = ( split ' ' )[1] if m!/!;
    print "$first/" . ( split ' ' )[1], "\n" if /^type/ and $first;
}

__DATA__
apple                    
apple MMaaa/gg/dd/MMhh/jj/lll
type  ID03
apple
apple MMsss/ff/dd
orange MMmm/ss
orange MMll/fff
apple
apple MMbb/gggg/iii
type  ID02
type  ID04
type  ID05
apple
apple MMhh/jj/lll
orange MMff/gg
apple
apple MMll/pp/ooo
type  ID09
type  ID03
```

Output:

```
MMaaa/gg/dd/MMhh/jj/lll/ID03
MMbb/gggg/iii/ID02
MMbb/gggg/iii/ID04
MMbb/gggg/iii/ID05
MMll/pp/ooo/ID09
MMll/pp/ooo/ID03
```

The script stores the 'path' string into `$first` if there's a `/` in the line.  If a line has `type` in it, it prints the 'path' and `type` together provided `$first` has a value.

Comment: It works! Thanks. What if the type value beginning is not ID? It can be any characters. For examples, swe_03_K and Re_M_9.

Comment: @Zoe - Is the "_________________group 5" labeling actually part of your data?

Comment: It is not a part of the data.

Comment: I tried in another similar data. But this data name is like MMxxx/xx/MMxxxx/xx. It would take the later (the second) MMxxxx/xx as the startpoint. Is it better if I use `if ($line =~ m/apple\s{1}MM((.*))/)  to grep the whole name path?

Comment: @Zoe - I've simplified the script and it should now handle the exceptions you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't address your matching problem, but you need to know some other things.

This is wrong.

```
while (@array = <FILE>) {
    foreach $line (@array) {
        ...
    }
}
```

What that does is read the entire contents of the file into `@array`, and then goes into the `while` loop.  The `while` loop executes exactly once (unless the file is empty and it executes zero times).  You're trying to walk through the file one line at a time, but you're combining two different loop constructs.

What you want to do is:

```
while ($line = <FILE>) {
    ... loop contents ...
}
```

This assigns one line at a time to `$line`.

You could also do it this way:

```
for $line (<FILE>) {
    .... loop contents
}
```

But that would read the entire  into a temporary array and then you'd iterate over it one array element at a time.